# Python custom module not found inside an example folder

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm working in a python project where I'm developing a custom lib (mylib) and using vscode.

```
/
└── mylib
    └── __init__.py
    ├── ...
```

If my program **split_example.py** is on the root, like below, I'm able to import and use **mylib**.

```
/
└── mylib
    └── __init__.py
    ├── ...
└── split_example.py
```

I would like to create a folder called **examples** and use **mylib**, but inside the folder **examples** I'm not able to import and use **mylib**.

```
/
└── mylib
    └── __init__.py
    ├── ...
└── examples
    └── split_example.py
```

Getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kleysonr/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.50794/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "/home/kleysonr/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.50794/pythonFiles/lib/python/old_ptvsd/ptvsd/__main__.py", line 432, in main
    run()
  File "/home/kleysonr/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.50794/pythonFiles/lib/python/old_ptvsd/ptvsd/__main__.py", line 316, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/data/dev/python/myproject/examples/split_example.py", line 3, in <module>
    from mylib.dataset import split
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mylib'
```

What should I do to have any program inside the folder **examples** able to `from mylib.dataset import split` ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time

Comment: How are you executing the code?

Comment: @BrettCannon ```python examples/split_example.py```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that because you are executing the code via `python examples/split_example.py`, Python is making `examples/` your current working directory, and thus your `mylib` directory isn't visible to Python. What you probably would rather do is `python -m examples.split_example` as that will make the current working directory the project root, making `mylib` visible to Python.

This will require that you add `__init__.py` to `examples` as well.

Answer (score -2):

Based on the @fabioconcina comment, I found this solutions.

Just include the following on the top of the file:

```py
from os import sys, path
PARENT_DIR = path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(PARENT_DIR)
```

Comment: This is a hack. Please use proper package structure conventions.

Comment: @PiotrRarus-ReinstateMonica may you provide an example ? `mylib` will be available in the pypi and I know that doing a pip install I can use the example without the hack, but I would like to have the examples working if someone just 'git clone' the repo, without pip install the module. That's the intention, have the examples working without installing the module.

Comment: Move them 1 level up and exclude that folder in setup.py. Check `scikit-learn` [repository](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn).